# C# Entity Framework Adding to Many-To-Many Table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

Is this a good practice to insert into a many-to-many table?

```
user = new User
        {
            Id = userId,
            UserName = username,
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName,
            UsersBooks = new List<UsersBooks>()
        };

        book = new Book
        {
            Title = "randomTitle2",
            Genre = "randomGenre2",
            UsersBooks = new List<UsersBooks>()
        };

        usersBooks = new UsersBooks
        {
            User = user,
            Book = book
        };
```

And at last I add it to the context

```
actContext.UsersBooks.AddAsync(usersBooks);
```

So I have this UsersBooks collection in each of the classes - user & book. One user can have many books and one book can be acquired by many users(copies of Harry Poter, let's say). So should I every time create a new

- usersBook and add it while passing the user and the book each time?
  Because I see that after that the book is added to it's according table, which is correct. Maybe I am asking if there is a better way in terms of most used by experienced developers

Comment: You don't need a `UsersBooks` class. Check [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `EF6` you have two options:

**1)** Since `EF6` supports many-to-many relation out-of-the-box you can go with that feature (that noted in the comment by vasily.sib).

**Pros**: your models and code look more cleaner without an excess model (`UsersBooks`)

**Cons**: it is not flexible way. In the future you may need to add additional properties to the relation table. This approach doesn't allow it

**2)** Handle many-to-many relation with two one-to-many realtions (like you did)

**Pros**: you can add any additional properties to this relation. It is a flexible approach

**Cons**: you code always should work with one more model (`UsersBooks`)

So, if you handle a simple scenario enough, then you can go with the first approach. Otherwise you need to consider the second.

BTW, currently, `EF core` doesn't support many-to-many relation

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to insert directly into the `UsersBooks` table.

Once you update the `users` list in `book`, or the `books` list in `user`, the relationship (in `UsersBooks`) will update automatically.

Actually, you don't need to declare a `UsersBooks` model for the *many-to-many* relationship. If you declare `ICollection<User>` in your `Book` *Code First* model, and also declare `ICollection<Book>` in the `User` model, the `UsersBooks` table will create in the database automatically by *Entity Framework*.